# Problema video de fondo no se carga en algunos Iphone HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema y es que, cree este video para que aparezca de fondo en una parte de la página y sucede que para usuarios del iphone 7 plus no ven la carga del video de forma correcta mientras que usuarios de iphone xr si y tengo entendido que para todos los android si funciona, no se que modificar para que el video se mantenga en todos los dispositivos y no buguee la página.

HTML

```
 <section id="bgPrincipal">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="absolute">
            <h1>La calidad en tu vaper</h1>
        </div>
        <section class="sect">
            <video onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" playsinline autoplay="true" muted="true" loop="true" id="bgvid">
                <source src="video/pexels-ivan-khmelyuk-7122120.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="video/pexels-ivan-khmelyuk-7122120.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </section>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#bgPrincipal{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.sect{
   max-height: 50rem;
}


video{
   width: 100vh;
}

@media(min-width: 500px) {
   video{
       width: 100%;
   }
}

.absolute{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.absolute h1{
   z-index: 100;
   margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.absolute h1::after{
   display: block;
   width: 30%;
   height: 10px;
   content: "";
   margin: auto;
   background-color: white;
}

.overlay{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Asi se ve cuando da error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se ve de forma correcta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Safari tanto en Desktop como en IPhone tiende a darte errores de diseños como cosas que no se visualicen o que desaparezcan de la nada, me paso antes y tuve que cambiar algunos estilos con webkit. Si probaste en Chrome, Firefox incluso en edge y funciona bien, lo mas seguro es que alguno de los estilos que uses o el mismo html no sea del todo compatible con safari.

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar BrowserStack y debbugear los estilos y ver si realmente carga el html de manera correcta en dispositivos iPhone, precisamente BrowserStack puedes testear en cualquier modelo de iPhone, Ipad, Tablet, OS Windows Mac, etc tiene una gran variedad de dispositivos, y puedes testearlo en tiempo real en su web.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera y dejando solo el source de mp4 a ver si funciona

```html
 <section id="bgPrincipal">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="absolute">
            <h1>La calidad en tu vaper</h1>
        </div>
        <section class="sect">
            <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="bgvid">
                <source src="video/pexels-ivan-khmelyuk-7122120.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </section>
</section>
```

Comment: no ha funcionado :(